# Querying sql table with multiple values

Tags: t-sql, distinct-values

I would like to query a sql table from below

```
ID Val
-------------
1 5
1 7
1 8
1 9
2 5
2 7
2 9
3 1
3 5
```

that would return the following set of results
query > select distinct ID from dbo.table where val in (5,7,9)

```
result
--------
ID
1
2
```

I run into a problem where a single row can match only one val from the subset and not all of them...

Comment: i don't understand the question... there is an ID of 1, 2, and 3 associated with the Val of 5. On what condition do you want to exclude 3 from the result set?

Comment: ID 3 doesn't contain values 7 and 9.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the rows are distinct:

```
SELECT ID
FROM your_table
WHERE Val IN (5,7,9)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Great and what about if the subset is dynamically generated?

Comment: @John: Then you need to create the string like `(5,7,9)` and also update the 3 in `COUNT(*) = 3` has to match the number of items. So if you have 4 items you need `COUNT(*) = 4`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I should probably count the params and pass it to the stored proc. What if I would use "not in" as an additional filter. Would i have to add count of those values together with previous 3 params? etc. having count(*) = 3+(not in params)